# How to make to webview returns to the previous page and does not show about: blank?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, back

P.S my English very bad and I have mistakes in text))) please sorry!

How to make to webview returns to the previous page and does not show about: blank?
here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return;
        }
        else {
            finish();
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
 @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            mbErrorOccured = true;
            showErrorLayout();
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            loadErrorPage();
        }
    }

    private void showErrorLayout() {
        mlLayoutRequestError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void loadErrorPage() {
        if(mWebView!=null){
            String htmlData ="<html><body><div align= center >Check your internet!</div></body>" ;
            mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlData, "text", "utf-8",null);
            mWebView.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

For example, the Google page loaded, then an error occurred and about: blank was loaded, and when the page is reloaded, the WebView reloads about: blank and not the Google page. How to make the Google page load on reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If about:blank page is already loaded and then you are reloading webview by calling `webView.reload()`, it will just reload the current page i.e. about:blank.

If you want to load previous page, just call `webView.goBack()` or you can directly load the url like this ->             `webView.loadUrl("<your.web.url>")`

Use [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) and [WebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient) if you want to have a better control on webview.

See the code below

First create WebViewClient and assign it to webview.

```
var currentUrl : String = "https://www.google.com";
webview.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
```

In WebViewClient's `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method, you can have you own logic to decide which web page you want's to load.

```
 class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient(){
        override fun onReceivedError(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?,
            error: WebResourceError?
        ) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
            // here display your custom error message with retry feature
            displayErrorDialog()
        }
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {

            // update current url

            if (url != null) {
                currentUrl = url
            }

            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to make the system like in the Opera browser, for example, if the page did not load, load my message and hide the standard error message and aks to reload this the page again?

Comment: And how to make that when page reload or page load, the previous one is automatically hidden?

Comment: @Appliker see updated answer. visit [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#HandlingNavigation) for better understanding.

Comment: I already have webview client and webchrome client see and download my code files here (https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2hHz/25DMkxh3U)

Comment: Thank u for answer,
I found solution by this `private WebChromeClient getChromeClient() {


        return new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressDialog.show();
                if (newProgress ==100){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        };
    }`